# Is Session.SessionTimeout is deprecated in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, session-timeout, global-asax

It seems like the following code is not working anymore in ASP.NET Identity?
Is this correct?

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Timeout = 5; // It has no impact to Session
}
```

And this code defines the session timeout only.

**STARTUP.AUTH.CS**

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{            
    var sessionTimeout = 20; // 

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(sessionTimeout),
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        CookieName = ".MyApp1_Authentication",
        SlidingExpiration = true
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you not mixing session timeout and cookie expiry period?

Comment: @trailmax May be... I assume they have to be equal, right?

Comment: very much depends on what you are trying to achieve. Cookie timeout is how long cookie is stored in the browser, authentication expiry depends on this. Session life is how long user data associated with the current visit is stored on the server. It makes sense to have session timeout and cookie expiry timespan to be identical, but they don't have to. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: @trailmax Thank you for your great explanation! Well.. Actually I need to set Session Time out so after N minutes of inactivity user on trying to do something user is gonna be redirected to the login  page. That's is what I need. Would be nice to see your answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cookie `ExpireTimeSpan` defines the length of life of the authentication cookie.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
    // other stuff
});
```

This will make authentication cookie invalid in 30 seconds. But it won't reload the page for the user, it will redirect user to login page only on the next request.

If you need the page automatically reloaded on cookie expire, you'll need some JavaScript in the browser to detect when the session is about to expire.

Not really an answer, as you already had that in you question. Just an extended comment -)